# re-execute javascript after log-in

Tags: javascript

I have a series of buttons that execute different functions when clicked. The function checks whether the user is logged in, and if so proceeds, if not it displays an overlay with ability to log in/create account.

What I want to do is re-execute the button click after log-in, without the user having to reclick it.

I have it working at the moment, but I'm pretty sure that what I'm doing isn't best practice, so looking for advice on how I can improve...

Here's what I'm doing: setting a global variable "pending_request" that stores the function to be re-run and in the success part of the log-in ajax request calling "eval(pending_request)"

Example of one of the buttons:

```
jQuery('#maybe_button').click(function() {
    pending_request = "jQuery('#maybe_button').click()"
    var loggedin = get_login_status();
    if (loggedin == true) {
        rec_status("maybe");
    }
});
```

.

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data === "User not found"){
        alert("Email or Password incorrect, please try again");
    }else{
        document.getElementById('loginscreen').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('locationover').style.display = 'none';
        eval(pending_request);
        pending_request = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Better suites for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why use `eval` at all? Just `$('#maybe_button').click();`

Comment: Thanks for introducing CodeReview - will check it out. the reason is there are several buttons that call different functions (sorry, should have been clearer in original post), so after log-in I need to know which of these buttons has been clicked to recall the correct function. Thats why I'm storing it in a variable and then using this in eval()

Answer (score 0):

Register a function to handle the click and then invoke that func directly without eval().

`jQuery('#maybe_button').on('click', myFunction)`

This executes `myFunction` when the button is clicked. Now you can "re-run" the function code every time you need it with `myFunction()`.

And btw since you are using `jQuery` you can do `$('#loginscreen').hide()` where `$` is an alias for `jQuery` that's auto defined.

**EDIT**

Please, take a look at the following code:

```
var pressedButton = null;

$('button1').on('click', function() {
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        pressedButton = $(this);
        return;    
    }

    // ...
});
```

And, in your success handler:

```
success: function() {
    // ...

    if (pressedButton) pressedButton.trigger('click');

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Dan. the problem I have is that there are several buttons on the page which call different functions. So, after the login I need to know which of these buttons was clicked (or function run) and then call the appropriate one on success of log-in

Comment: So you are saying that you have various buttons. Each button triggers a different function. Before login a user may press more than one button. This will cause more than one function to be executed. After login you want all of those functions to be re-executed. Did i understand the problem correctly?

Comment: BTW - why don't you just hide all those buttons before the user is logged in?